# Inflating a mesh within simulation zone?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am 3D-printing in metal and do inflate these bodies. Find here a short video about this fascinating tech:
https://vimeo.com/862457161?share=copy

So this accordion test was just a proof of concept, to test the feasibility of inflating 3D-printed steel. Now I would like to do research on geometries of higher complexity, here you find the design vision: https://vimeo.com/856147115?share=copy

As most of these ideas are highly speculative, a simulation would make very much sense. Especially as I would like to work with ribbed relief structures on my bodies, to finetune the inflation-deformation.

Such a print is rather expensive in money and time, so even a rough simulation would be very helpful in testing out the outcome before the action.

So that's why I would like to simulate this process using simulation zone. This works pretty well within Blender simulation already, but it would be perfect if I could do this within geo-nodes, where I develop the generative geometry. I would be so happy about some guidance how to increase the pressure within a mesh inside of simulation zone, if this is feasible at all.

Any hints how to approach this problem would be highly appreciated. Many thanks Mischa

Comment: In terms of Blender, this means you made a *Cloth* simulation that inflates a compressed, accordion-crumpled cube, and now you want to do the same thing in *Simulation* nodes? What's wrong with the solution you already have?